# WebView zooming with scroll limiting

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview, zooming

The basic idea of what I want to achieve is to be able to zoom into the content within a WebView, but limit the scrolling so that the content doesn't show some padding that is at the top and bottom when zoomed in. I know the height of the padding in question.

I've currently extended the WebView class, and overridden `onScrollChanged`
so that I can get information on when we are scrolling and how far. This is all easy enough, and works fine (i.e. I get the info I need).

The problem comes when trying to limit the scrolling itself. I can correctly limit it so that the top padding is never visible, but for some reason I cannot fathom the bottom just will not limit correctly.

Here's the code I currently have within `onScrollChanged`:

```
@Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        float totalPadding = 250 * scaleFactor;
        float padding = totalPadding / 2;

        float paddingTopStart = padding;
        float paddingBottomStart = (contentHeight * scaleFactor) + paddingTopStart;

        if (t > paddingBottomStart) {
            setScrollY((int) paddingBottomStart);
        } else if (t < paddingTopStart) {
            setScrollY((int) paddingTopStart);
        }
    }
```

The scale factor is obtained in onScaleChanged and saved as a class variable. `totalPadding` is the overall amount of padding (padding at the top + padding at the bottom). The padding is equal on both sides, hence `padding = totalPadding / 2`.

The `paddingBottomStart` is what I assume is the issue. I was certain that the maths involved was correct, yet it still doesn't work. If anyone has any suggestions they would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the reason my calculations weren't coming out as correct is because value t is actually the scroll value at the top of the screen. Consequently I needed to take this into account when doing the calculations!